# Hosting maven generated site on glassfish

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, maven-site-plugin

I have glassfish server that is used to host jenkins for continuous integration. The build generates a maven site. Is there a way I can deploy this maven site into glassfish so it can be viewed remotely?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Bundle it as a war file.  Just create an empty .war and stick the files/dir structure in.  Make a WEB-INF/web.xml and define the welcome page as the index page.